# Having trouble with the following python regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi there I have following type of configuration file that I am trying to parse using regex in Python.
You will see that lines starting with test occurs twice and I am after the all the second instance which has two distinct keywords, description and no shutdown.

```
   test 68068070 same "random-text" someone 68068070 new
       int "random-test" new
       exit
       int "somemore-random-text" new
       exit
    exit
    test 58698496 name "58698496" someone 1 new
       interface "some random text" new
       exit
    exit
    test 4035849058 name "can be any random text" someone 76060600 new
       int "another random text" new
       exit
    exit
    test 806406450 name "random text goes here" someone 89899 new
    exit
    test 68068070 same "random-text" someone 68068070 new
       description "random-text-here"
       Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
       no shutdown
    exit  
    test 806406450 name "random text goes here" someone 89899 new
     description "random-text-here"
       Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
       no shutdown
    exit  
    test 58698496 name "58698496" someone 1 new
     description "random-text-here"
         Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
       no shutdown
    exit  
    test 58698496 name "58698496" someone 1 new
    description "random-text-here"
       Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
       no shutdown
    exit  
    test 4035849058 name "can be any random text" someone 76060600 new
    description "random-text-here"
       Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
       no shutdown
    exit
```

From the above text I want only capture following instances:

```
test 68068070 same "random-text" someone 68068070 new
   description "random-text-here"
   Lots of random text goes here
       no shutdown
   exit
   no shutdown
exit  
test 806406450 name "random text goes here" someone 89899 new
 description "random-text-here"
   Lots of random text goes here
       no shutdown
   exit
   no shutdown
exit  
test 58698496 name "58698496" someone 1 new
 description "random-text-here"
   Lots of random text goes here
       no shutdown
   exit
   no shutdown
exit  
test 58698496 name "58698496" someone 1 new
description "random-text-here"
   Lots of random text goes here
       no shutdown
   exit
   no shutdown
exit  
test 4035849058 name "can be any random text" someone 76060600 new
description "random-text-here"
   Lots of random text goes here
       no shutdown
   exit
   no shutdown
exit
```

The regex that I have tried at regex101 is the following:

```
test\s\d{1,10}\s.+?new\s+description.*?no\sshutdown\s*exit
```

With gs flags turned on.

[regex101link](https://regex101.com/r/yMsE4r/1/)

The issue with my regex is that it captures from the beginning of the text, so it captures everything.
How do I make the regex so it does not capture following text:

```
   test 68068070 same "random-text" someone 68068070 new
       int "random-test" new
       exit
       int "somemore-random-text" new
       exit
    exit
    test 58698496 name "58698496" someone 1 new
       interface "some random text" new
       exit
    exit
    test 4035849058 name "can be any random text" someone 76060600 new
       int "another random text" new
       exit
    exit
    test 806406450 name "random text goes here" someone 89899 new
    exit
```

I want my match to start from the following text and onwards and return any similar items of this type:

```
   test 68068070 same "random-text" someone 68068070 new
       description "random-text-here"
       Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
       no shutdown
    exit
```

Any help on how can I tweak or change my regex to fix this.
I have tried to use negative lookahead i.e. not match int or even postive lookahead to look for description but i have had no success with neither of these.
Thanks

Another issue that I have run into is as follows:

There are cases where no shutdown occurs many time in a single instance for example:

```
   test 68068070 same "random-text" someone 68068070 new
       description "random-text-here"
       Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
    exit  
        Lots of random text goes here
        no shutdown
       exit
    exit  
        Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
       exit
    exit  
     Lots of random text goes here
           no shutdown
        exit
      exit
        no shutdown
    exit
exit
```

How do i pick this scenario all the way to last no shutdown.On this one the regex comes and stops at the first no shutdown.
So this regex works:

```
test\s\d{1,10}\s[^\n]+new\s+description.+?no\sshutdown\s+exit
```

But stops at the first no shutdown. Any ideas how I go down to the last no shutdown.

Comment: regex is not a good choice for parsing formatted multiline nested data formats.

Comment: Hi there, any ideas what else can i use to extract the text i require. Unfortunately this is vendor specific text output from a device which is not JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negated character class:

```
test\s\d{1,10}\s[^\n]+new\s+description.+?no\sshutdown\s+exit
#               ^^^^^^  [^\n] matches anything but line break
```

Make sure you are using DOTALL or `s` mode for your regex.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yMsE4r/2)

In your regex `.*` matches any character including line breaks since you're using `s` mode hence it matches too much across the blocks. `[^\n]` on the other hand only matches within same line.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thanks your suggestion has fixed my problem, although i don't understand how [^n] is working. But i have edited my post and you will see i have run into another problem where a block has lots of no shutdown statement, and i want to capture all of them. See the updated post, any idea how i capture this scenario please.

Comment: I have already explained in answer that `[^\n]` matches anything but line break.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, just checking my understanding to make sure i understand the regex and how it is working, sorry I am new to regex and trying to understand how it is working. My understanding on what you have suggested is as follows:  This bit on it own vprn\s[^\n]+, it matches the vprn literal then a space char, then we are saying do not match the newline char and but using the + quantifier, keep matching until the end of the first line. So when you say that [^\n] only matches within same line, i don't understand how does this jump to next line i.e. \s+description.+? etc.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. `\s+description.+?` matches across lines due to use of `s` or `DOTALL` mode which force `.` (dot) to match any character including newlines.

Comment: test\s\d{1,10}\s[^\n]+\s+description, how does \s+ allows to jump on the next line? \s matches any whitespace char and + says one or more. Does \s have a special meaning when used with re.DOTALL flag? I can understand that description.+?, this . matches across newlines but before this we only use \s and no . operator.

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace including newlines. Don't get confused between `DOTALL` or `s` mode and `\s`. I suggest you to please read some regex tutorials to build good understanding.